# php guzzle issue with requestAsync call to wordsAPI

Tags: php, guzzle

did anyone have an issue related to php guzzle and simple request call to wordsAPI?

I'm currently developing on my localhost using XAMPP. This is what I intend to do:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

$client = new Client();
$promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/example', [
    "headers" => [
        "x-rapidapi-host" => "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key" => apikey
    ]
]);
$promise->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
    }
);

$promise->wait();
```

However, it fails miserably with the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have not seen the posted code yet but ConnectException is thrown in the event of a networking error, have you tried checking connections yours, it can be that the api provider is having some connection issues, have  you tried along with postman or insomnia or any other http clients

Comment: Yes, I tried with JS and fetch, worked fine.

Comment: I visited the wordsapiv1 website & they ask for headers `array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "<required>",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )` I guess you are not passing these, without passing these I tried on browser was giving connection error for me as well